# Pass back original SQL operation row count, after trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a piece of legacy VB6 code that is inserting data into a sql server 2000 database table. The code uses the row count returned for various purposes.

We recently put a trigger on the table which calls a stored procedure to update another table. It now appears that the VB6 code is picking up the row count returned from the triggered procedure, rather than the original operation.

Is there anyway of ensuring that the appropriate row count is returned? Can we "pass" the original row count through the trigger somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) inside the trigger.